# Инициализация двусвязного списка

Tags: c++, указатели, двусвязный-список

Пишу программу по двусвязным спискам, написал функцию для добавления элемента, но не могу понять, на что ругается компилятор:

```
void addorder(Order** root, string* data) {
    if (*root) {

    }
    else{
        *root = (Order*)malloc(sizeof(Order));
        **root->place = data[0];
        **root->number = data[1];
        **root->surname = data[2];
        **root->date = data[3];
        **root->next = NULL;
        **root->prev = NULL;
    }
}
```

Ошибка: выражение должно иметь тип указателя.

Comment: Намек: посмотрите в таблицу приоритетов — для операций разыменования и обращения к члену.

Comment: @Harry, если пишу (**root)->..., то Visual Studio подчёркивает первую скобку и выдаёт ошибку "Выражение должно иметь тип указателя"

Comment: Всё, я разобрался. Одна звезда была лишняя, т.к. -> заменяет собой *p.